# Java airline seat program using two dimensional array has variable assignment errors

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a program to assign seats in an airplane using a two dimensional array. The program will have 5 rows and 4 columns. I am to ask the user to select a seat such as A5.The program checks the array to see if the seat is available & places an "X" in the position of the array if it is available. If it’s unavailable, a message gets displayed to the user. The program will continue until the user enters -1 to quit. I found a similar program which uses a string named "q" to exit, but I need to change it to -1. Would I just cast -1 to a string or is there a better way to do it? I had tried  something like "if (seatNumber.equals(-1))", but that doesn't seem to work. There is a light bulb alert icon on the left hand side with a message that says "the local variable q is not used". Also, there is another lightbulb alert icon with a message that says "the local variable numberOfSeatsAvailable is not used". I am using Eclipse and the program will not run. A dialog box pops up that says that has "Errors in Workspace" at the top. It also says "errors exist in required project(s). It lists the directory that the project is in & asked to proceed with launch. When I proceed with the launch I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
    at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1670)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1538)
    at AirplaneSeating.main(AirplaneSeating.java:44)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AirplaneSeating
{

    static int filled = 0 ;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // two- dimensional array with 5 rows and 4 columns 
        char[][] layout = new char [5][4] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            layout[i][0] = 'A' ;
            layout[i][1] = 'B' ;
            layout[i][2] = 'C' ;
            layout[i][3] = 'D' ;
        }

        String seatNumber = " " ; 
        String q = "  " ;
        int numberOfSeatsAvailable = 20 ;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Airplane Seating Reservation System.") ;
        System.out.println("Please enter the seat (e.g.- 1A) you wish to reserve.") ;
        System.out.println("Enter -1 to exit.") ;
        printSeats(layout) ;
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        seatNumber = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        if (seatNumber.equals("q"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Program ended.") ;
                    System.exit(0) ;
                } 
        while((filled < 20) && (seatNumber.length() > 0))
        {
            int row = seatNumber.charAt(0) - '1' ;
            int col = seatNumber.charAt(1) - 'A';
            if (row < 0 || row > 5 || col < 0 || col > 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Input error. Enter seat to assign (e.g., '1A')," +
                    "or -1 to quit.");
                seatNumber = scan.nextLine() ;
                if (seatNumber.equals("q"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Program ended.") ;
                    System.exit(0) ;
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                //put an X in the assigned seat and print seating arrangement
                if (layout[row][col] != 'X')
                {
                    layout[row][col] = 'X' ;
                    filled++ ; 
                    //System.out.println(" ") ;
                    printSeats(layout) ;
                }
                if (filled < 20)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter seat to assign (e.g., '1A')," +
                        "or q to quit.");
                    seatNumber = scan.nextLine();
                    if (seatNumber.equals("q"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Program ended.") ;
                        System.exit(0) ;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }       
        System.out.println("Final seat assignments: "); 
        printSeats(layout); 
    }

    private static void printSeats(char[][] seats)
    {
        System.out.println("Row") ;
        for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + "  " + 
                seats[i][0] + " " + seats[i][1] + "  " + seats[i][2] + " " + seats[i][3]) ;
        }
        int numberOfSeatsAvailable = (20 - filled);
        System.out.println("There are " + numberOfSeatsAvailable + " seats available.");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }  //end main
}  //end class
```

Comment: When asking questions about errors, please always include the full and complete copy-paste of the error output in the question. And add comments in the code where you get the errors. Please [edit] your question to improve it. Also please take some time to refresh [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and don't forget the *minimal* part of your [mcve].

Comment: The problem is that you closed your Scanner (seatNumber). You wouldn't be allowed to open another Scanner on System.in, because closing a scanner also closes the stream the scanner is based on. Just keep the scanner open, and it will automatically close when the program closes. Or you could close it as the last line of your ``public static main(String[])`` method.

Answer (score 1):

As scan.close() has already been invoked before in

```
seatNumber = scan.nextLine();
scan.close();
```

that's why below line will cause IllegalStateException.

```
System.out.println("Input error. Enter seat to assign (e.g., '1A')," +
                    "or -1 to quit.");
seatNumber = scan.nextLine() ;
```

Possible solution :

1. use

   ```
    Scanner scan = null;
     try {Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //logic} 
    finally { if(null != scan) scan.close();}
   ```
2. use

   ```
    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)){ // logic}finally{}
   ```

Comment: I took the scan.close syntax out & it does do most of what its supposed  to do after I click on the  proceed button in the "Errors in Workspace" dialog box. It puts an "x" in the array position, but when i type in q to exit I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at AirplaneSeating.main(AirplaneSeating.java:44)

Comment: What I need to have is for the program to quit when the user types in -1. It also doesn't seem to work if its not capital letters